Calling the mapped port in Docker
I have a container running and the service inside is running on port 8000. And I have port mapped the container when I use "docker run" command. And the service inside the container is running fine and the container is running fine. But can't call that port from my host machine. Can you help fix that.
Dockerfile
# [Choice] Ubuntu version: hirsute, bionic, focal
FROM  ubuntu:18.04

# [Optional] Uncomment this section to install additional OS packages.
# RUN apt-get update && export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
#     && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends <your-package-list-here>
WORKDIR /workspaces

# copy web2py source
ADD web2py .
ENV TZ=Asia/Yangon \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-ldap python-pip python-tk ipython graphviz-dev unzip tzdata

# get and install web2py
# RUN  unzip web2py_src.zip && \
#         rm web2py_src.zip && \
#         mv web2py/handlers/wsgihandler.py web2py/wsgihandler.py && \
#     rm -rf web2py/applications/welcome && \
#     rm -rf web2py/applications/examples

# add default route
# ADD routes.py web2py/

RUN pip install --upgrade pymongo
RUN pip install requests
RUN pip install pylibmc
RUN pip install pygraphviz
RUN pip install pycrypto
RUN pip install fileutils

EXPOSE 8000

# CMD ["python", "web2py.py", "-i", "0.0.0.0", "-p", "8000"]

image build command
docker build -t web2py .

docker run command
docker run -it -p 8000:8000 web2py

and then inside that container I run the web2py on port 8000
I have tried running the container with this command
docker run -it -p 0.0.0.0:8000:8000 web2py

still doesn't work either.
When I run docker ps command I have the container running like this
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS             PORTS                                           NAMES
84c31515e2d7   web2py                "/bin/bash"              About an hour ago   Up About an hour   0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, :::8000->8000/tcp       amazing_yonath


Any reason to not start the server using the Dockerfile CMD?  In particular, in the Dockerfile CMD, you have an option -i 0.0.0.0 which could be important; what is the underlying application, and what host and port is it actually listening on?

I commented out the CMD instruction since I want to run and stop the server without having to stop and start the container. The underlying application is web2py and I'm running it on port 8000

What address are you listening on?  (127.0.0.1 vs. 0.0.0.0 matters a lot and could cause this problem.)  What's wrong with stopping (and deleting) the container?

I think I'm listening on 0.0.0.0 . Can you explain me why that 127.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.0 cause this problem? I'm actually rookie to docker and haven't familiar yet.

Docker app server ip address 127.0.0.1 difference of 0.0.0.0 ip.  TL/DR: If the server only listens on 127.0.0.1 then it won't be reachable from outside its own container.  Also the default behavior of e.g. Flask is to only listen on 127.0.0.1 unless you configure it otherwise.

My problem could that be this case. The web2py is running on 127.0.0.1:8000 inside container and also my container is port mapped and working fine. And I can't call the server from my host machine. Now I know I should change the ip for the host inside the container. Thank you so much for pointing out, sir.
